# Kubuntu will not boot after repartitioning internal drive

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, fsck

I have a machine with a 250GB SSD. I had 7 partitions on it: the first 5 from Windows 10, with the EFI as partition 2. I deleted the Windows recovery partition 3 and the Windows partitions 4 and 5, and then deleted my Linux partition 6 (with an EXT4 fs) and recreated it with the remaining space, then rebooted my machine, and it failed to boot.

The problem I assume is that my previous file system is in the middle of the partition and cannot be read. As a result, it boots into the GRUB command line.

When I run `e2fsck` on the partition, I get

> Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda4

I really don't want to delete and recreate my file system as there was lots of work saved on my computer. Can I make a script to run `e2fsck -b` with every single possible superblock, or is there something else wrong with what I did?

Comment: *"deleted my Linux partition"* - then your data is toast

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Recovering ext4 superblocks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks)

Comment: Android Dev that's not how the file system works. Unless the data is written over, it still exists on the disk, otherwise it would not be possible to expand a partition for example when migrating to a larger SD card on a raspberry pi. I found another forum that recommended testdisk which was able to find my filesystem and restore the majority of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Using testdisk I was able to locate the file system and restore the majority of my files. I think the main problem was trying to expand the partition from the starting block without properly moving the file system blocks.

Comment: When you move the head end of the boot partition (where the `/boot` directory resides), `grub` will not find it. If the expansion of the partition was made correctly, for example with `gparted`, it will be enough to re-install `grub` to make the computer boot correctly. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing - Anyway, I'm glad you were able to repair your system with `testdisk` :-)